# Centering the middle of three divs and positioning the other two relative to the middle one

Tags: css

Sorry if the title is confusing. Basically, I'm working on a tumblr theme where I need three adjacent divs wrapped in a fixed-width container. None of their contents are fixed, so they all have variable widths. The middle div should always be centered to the container, while the divs to the left and right will always be "touching" the middle div, and, thus, move around as the middle div's width changes (the left and right s may be images, so text-align doesn't always work). Plus, I may also need to hide the left, right, or both the left and right divs.

Here's a conceptual image:

[image]

I can obtain this using flexboxes easily ([JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/velocirabbit/ytye51zg/)), but [flex only has 86% global support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

This is the closest I could get without using flexboxes, but I can't get that middle div (with the text) centered to the title div, while preserving the relative positions of the two images on either side: [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/velocirabbit/q3Lcz4u8/)

```
* {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
body {
    height: 200px;
}
/* just to get rid of scrollbar */
 p {
    margin: 0;
}
.title {
    background: #aaa;
    height: 22px;
    width: 450px;
    /* for example */
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.container {
    background: #abc;
    float: left;
}
.lr {
    transform: translate(0, -100%);
}
.left {
    background: green;
    float: left;
}
.left img {
    transform: translate(-100%);
}
.center {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 2;
}
.right {
    background: blue;
    float: right;
}
.right img {
    transform: translate(100%);
}
.left img, .right img {
    height: 100%;
}

<div class="title">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="center">CENTERCENTERCENTERCEN</div>
        <div class="lr">
            <div class="left">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/7bvErJN.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/q8Mq0YZ.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Other people have mentioned trying to display the title as a table, but that would require centering the middle cell to the whole row, and having the cells to the left and right take up the rest of the space, and I'm not sure if you can do that when their widths aren't fixed.

Anyone know of any other solutions?

Comment: @Danko That doesn't center the text in the middle div. I have the middle div shrink-wrapped so the two images on either side are right up against the text, and now I'm trying to center the middle div while keeping the positions of the two images relative to that middle div (without using Javascript or flex).

Comment: Yep my mistake if you can change a little your markup you can do this http://jsfiddle.net/ytye51zg/32/

Comment: @Danko Woah, that works perfectly! I tested out adding more to the left side and centering the whole thing and it doesn't break: http://jsfiddle.net/velocirabbit/ytye51zg/33/ It even works if you remove the text in the center.

Comment: Yep that's because the elemnts for left and right are inside the center one and can be positioned relative to that.

Comment: That's smart. I didn't think of positioning the left and right absolutely inside the center. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change your HTML then apply this:

- First move the left and right elements inside center:

  ```
  <div class="center">
      CENTERCENTERCENTERCEN
      <div class="left">
         testtest<img src="http://i.imgur.com/7bvErJN.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="right">
         <img src="http://i.imgur.com/q8Mq0YZ.jpg" />
      </div>
  </div>
  ```
- Then on the CSS :

  ```
  /*Keep the center container on the middle*/
  .title {
     text-align:center;
   }
  .center {
     position:relative;
     display:inline-block;
  }

  /*Position elements based on the relative center parent*/
  .left {
     position:absolute;
     top:0;left:0;
     transform:translateX(-100%)
  }
  .right {
     position:absolute;
     top:0;right:0;
     transform:translateX(100%)
  }
  ```

Check this [`DemoFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/qehmzhdf/)

Comment: Fiddle link broken. I'm curious to see this though, good approach.

Comment: @Blunderfest fixed link

Comment: Thanks. This still doesn't seem to be able to handle a large amount of text in the middle container without hiding one of the outside containers. Perhaps that is acceptable to the OP?

Comment: @Blunderfest you mean if the windos size is too small the left is lost? http://jsfiddle.net/qehmzhdf/1/ .Since the widths aren't fixed and can change can be impossible just with css may need to set some max-width on the center

Comment: On my view it also loses the right, but I see what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using `position: absolute` should help in this.

I changed your HTML to following:

```
<div class="title">
    <div class="container">
        <img class="left" src="http://i.imgur.com/7bvErJN.jpg" />
        <div class="center">CENTERCENTERCENTERCEN</div>
        <img class="right" src="http://i.imgur.com/q8Mq0YZ.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.title {
    background: #aaa;
    height: 22px;
    width: 450px;
    /* for example */
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.container {
    background: #abc;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}
.center {
    background: red;
}
.left, .right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
.left {
    right: 100%;
}
.right {
    left: 100%;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3Lcz4u8/5/)**

Comment: Is there a way for this to accommodate larger text? http://jsfiddle.net/q3Lcz4u8/7/

Comment: When you add a lot of text in the middle container with this approach, the outside containers disappear as in the fiddle I linked to.

Comment: @Blunderfest yeah seems not possible to fix with just css.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated to show OP Update**

No need for flex here, why not just use percentages? Float all the containers and put the percentages as relative to the sizes you want. (50% for the middle, 25% for the outside containers).

You can use the outside containers as wrappers so you can still use a border on the inner containers without messing up the sizing. Then just float the inner containers *within* the outside containers (if that makes sense). The example below just floats the inner `p` tags to the outer containers.

This makes it always hug the inner container, while keeping relative sizes and also keeping the middle centered.

Example below:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8u6xuwj2/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="flexa">
    <div class="left">
        <p>leftleft</p>
    </div>
    <div class="center"><p>CENTERCENTdsfdfdERCENTsdfdfsfERCEN</p></div>
    <div class="right">
        <p>ri</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">BOTTOMOMOM</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  background: #aaaaaa;
  overflow: hidden;
}
p{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.container {
  width: 500px;
  /* for example */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.right p{ /* This is what makes it work. This could be a div with class of inner or something like that. */
  float:left;
}
.left p{ 
  float:right;
}
.flexa div{
  float:left;
}
.left {
   width:25%;
}
.center {
  width: 50%;
}
.right {
  width:25%;
}
.bottom {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Fixed width divs don't work here. The middle div should shrink wrap to the contents so the images are right up against the text. In your code, if the contents of the middle div are too short or too long it looks weird.

Comment: @velocirabbit Hmm... That is an interesting issue with it. The link provided in the comments to your question though doesn't seem to scale gracefully with lots of text either? http://jsfiddle.net/pzafp2Lx/

Comment: In that one, I set a fixed width and no overflow:hidden set. If you expand the window size so it's large enough that there's space around the title div it looks good still (despite the lack of overflow:hidden). But, yeah, you're right; overflow;hidden should be set.